# How to receive sender's name in MQTT

Tags: java, mqtt

I need to get name of user, who sent the message and after display it with the message. For example:

```
username1: message1
username2: message2
```

But I didn't find any method which can help to receive sender's name in `MqttMessage` class. Does it exist and if yes which method should I use?

Comment: At minimum, do you have any source code part to provide? If possible add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: @Bsquare, yes, I have code, but there's no need in it, in my view. I only ask about   the existing of one method

Answer (score 0):

The `onMessageArrived()` callback comes with only `topic` and `MqttMessage` parameters.

However payload is binary data, you can have any data inside the payload.Once client receives payload you could parse the payload for required information.

You need to change your payload to include required parameters.